# measure elements on windows resize (Jquery)

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build slider (button driven). So far I managed to get slides move as I want and reset if clicked outside container. Measurements are taken via JQuery. I am struggling with re measuring elements on the fly :

1. I am trying to make jquery check sizes (width) of elements when windows resizes on the fly (tablet landscape versus portrait). I have created function "MeasureDimensions" however I don't think it works as expected. It does work when I resize window and refresh the page, but not when I tilt the screen. What would be the best way to tackle this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function MeasureDimensions() {
    var $container = $('.container'),
      $slider = $('.container ul'),
      $box = $('li', $slider),
      W = $container.width(), // Container : 5000px as 5 X 1000px = 5000px
      N = $box.length, // 5 li's within UL 
      C = 0; // Counter

    $slider.width(W * N);

    $('#prev, #next').click(function() {
      C = (this.id == 'next' ? ++C : --C) < 0 ? N - 1 : C % N;
      $slider.stop().animate({
        left: -C * W
      }, 400);

    });

    $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
      var container = $('.container');

      if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        $slider.stop().animate({
          left: W - W
        }, 400);
        C = 0;
      }
    });

  };

  MeasureDimensions();
  $(window).resize(MeasureDimensions);
  
  //added this :
  
  $(window).on("orientationchange",function(){
 MeasureDimensions();
    
    //no effect?
});

});
```

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
}

.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 1000px;
  background: #333;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.container ul {
  list-style-position: outside;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container ul li {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1000px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 200px;
  font-size: 4rem;
  color: #fff;
}

.container ul li:nth-child(even) {
  background: #252E7F;
}

.container ul li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #121740;
}


/* Buttons 
===========*/

#next,
#prev {
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#next {
  border-right: 2px solid #fff;
}

.container span:hover {
  background: #7F7F7F;
  transition: ease 0.2s all;
}


@media (max-width: 980px) {
  .container {
    width: 310px;
  }
  
  .container ul li {
    width: 310px;
    font-size:1.5rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>Slide Number One </li>
    <li>Slide Number Two</li>
    <li>Slide Number Three</li>
    <li>Slide Number Four</li>
    <li>Slide Number Five</li>
  </ul>
  <span id="next">Next</span>
  <span id="prev">Previous</span>
</section>
```

Any help - much appreciated.

Comment: You are looking for the `orientationchange` event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/orientationchange . Add both, `orientationchange` + `resize`

Comment: I tried to add orientationchange but this does not give any effect. I have updated my snippet. Could you please have a look a it?

Comment: It must work. Try with the vanilla javascript listener but orientation change must work when you rotate from portrait to landscape and viceversa. What browser are you using?